# C++ constructor every arguments have "=2.0" after?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm beginning in C++ and I found this code of a class

```
class Box
{
  public:
  static int objectCount;
  // Constructor definition
  Box(double l=2.0, double b=2.0, double h=2.0)
  {
     cout <<"Constructor called." << endl;
     length = l;
     breadth = b;
     height = h;
     // Increase every time object is created
     objectCount++;
  }
  double Volume()
  {
     return length * breadth * height;
  }
private:
  double length;     // Length of a box
  double breadth;    // Breadth of a box
  double height;     // Height of a box
};
```

However, I don't understand why there are "=2.0" after every arguments of the 
constructor... Can someone explain me?

Comment: If you're beginning C++, it may be more productive to read a beginner's C++ book.

Comment: These are default function arguments, you should do a search about that

Answer (score 0):

It's a default value for the function or the method parameter. If a function/method call does not specify this parameter, the function/method call uses the default value. This effectively makes the parameter optional, as opposed to required. Optional parameter must follow any required parameters. Required parameters cannot follow optional parameters.

A constructor is, effectively, a method call for the purpose of this question. The end result here is that all parameters to this class's constructor are optional. If any are not specified, they default to 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Those are default arguments.The fact that the particular function you ask about is a class constructor is not special; any function in C++ can have default arguments.

When a function is called, a default argument is what gets passed to the function, if you do not explicitly write anything.

Let's say we declare a function

```
foo(int m = 1)
```

Now, if we make the call

```
foo(9);
```

Nine gets passed to the function. However, we can also make the call

```
foo();
```

This time, the number one gets passed to the function.

A default argument is what automatically gets passed to the function if you don't bother to explicitly specify what you want passed to it. Default arguments are handy if you want a function to have a kind of default behavior, and only sometimes, on a rare occasion, have it do something differently.

In the case of the Box class you are working with, the default arguments were created for a kind of a silly reason. It was done so that the programmer could be lazy, create a box example, and play around with it; all without bothering to specify what they wanted the boxes initial length, width and height to be.